# Using select * in Sqlite3 is returning bizarre overlapping text at command prompt

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using Windows 10, running sqlite3.exe from command prompt. I have a database table like this

```
create table users 
(
    id integer,
    name text,
    user_id integer,
    primary key(id)
);
```

When I do a query like this

```
sqlite> select id, user_id, name from users limit 1;
```

I get

```
1|1234|johnathan
```

That's fine, but when I'm doing it in the right order (id, name, then user_id)

```
sqlite> select id, name, user_id from users limit 1;
```

I get

```
|1234nathan
```

I'm learning SQL right now and have been playing around with this single file for a while but I really can't imagine why anything I've done would cause this behavior. Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it's because there was a carriage return at the end of the names.